# How to pass datetime parameter from angular 2 to wcf service?

Tags: c#, angular, web-services, wcf

```
Let's assume we have one method in WCF service with below class as parameter.

public interface ILoginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetMember/", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = 
    WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Member GetMember(Member request);
}

[DataContract]
public Class Member
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Datetime BOD { get; set; }
}
```

Above is the sample code of wcf service method and parameter.
    Now how can we pass BOD from angular 2 to GetMember method. We can't convert 
    DOB as string datatype because we have already used this service in other 
    application as well. This method is working fine if we remove BOD from 
    Member class. But when we are trying to pass datetime from angular then it 
    throws 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Can you please include your typescript code as well.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime values in WCF are serialized according to the xs : dateTime rules of the XML Schema (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). If the non-WCF clients conform to those rules, they should have no problem in sending/receiving DateTime values to/from WCF services.

Try sending date in UTC format From TypeScript To Service.